# SQL Server ORDER BY when using DATENAME function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,DATE1) 
AS varchar (5)) + '-' + CAST(DATENAME(m,ec2.DATE2) 
AS varchar(3)) AS [Month],
CAST(AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(day,DATE1, DATE2) 
AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS tt
FROM tbl3
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,DATE1) AS 
varchar (5)) + '-' + CAST(DATENAME(m,ec2.DATE2) 
AS varchar(3))
ORDER BY [Month]
```

So in the above query I have results for 2 different years so its sorting year in integer wise but Month according to alphabets(as its `DATENAME`)
Examples:

```
2013-Dec 4.45
2013-Nov 5.55
2014-Jan 2.35
2014-Jan 2-85
```

The problem is I am using `DATE2` in my aggregate function(`Avg`) and hence can't use it in `ORDER BY` clause.

Anyone has a solution for this problem. I will be really thankful if you can help me. I read other questions regarding this problem but didn't find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, select two more fields: the year and the month -- both numeric -- and sort by those.

Comment: Thanks Darius that did it.. I am feeling so stupid right now :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convoluted way, but works in any situation. Use CTE to solve your issue as below:

```
With CTE as (
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,DATE1) 
AS varchar (5)) + '-' + CAST(DATENAME(m,ec2.DATE2) 
AS varchar(3)) AS [Month],
CAST(AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(day,DATE1, DATE2) 
AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS tt
FROM tbl3
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,DATE1) AS 
varchar (5)) + '-' + CAST(DATENAME(m,ec2.DATE2) 
AS varchar(3))
Select * from CTE
ORDER BY 
DATEPART(yyyy, cast([Month] as datetime)),
DATEPART(mm, cast([Month] as datetime));
```

Comment: Thanks Binaya. Your answer is also correct but i preferred Darius way as my actual query was already very complicated with lot of sub-queries. But definately marking it as answer as its the best solution to do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you can order by Year/Month as Darius X suggested. You can also use a cross apply to "wrap" your calculation. Not sure it would solve your specfic problem, but for additional information. I figure out the MatchStatus in the CROSS APPLY then use MatchStatus in the SELECT & GROUP BY clauses.

```
SELECT
    MatchStatus,
    COUNT(*)
FROM MPI.ACTData.Matches
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN MatchScore >= 69 THEN 'Match' 
                ELSE 'Review' END MatchStatus) ms
GROUP BY MatchStatus
```

Comment: Thanks earl.. I didn't knew about CROSS APPLY.. Will try to use it for future queries..